# I keep getting the same error when using HuggingFacePipeline

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model

I am a beginner in generative AI and currently, I watching a tutorial about it but have met an issue that cannot resolve.

```py
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain import PromptTemplate, HuggingFaceHub, LLMChain
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, pipeline
import os
    
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = "my api" 
model_id = "google/flan-t5-base"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_id)


pipeline = pipeline("text2text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=128)
local_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline)

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["name"],
    template="Can you tell me about the politician {name}"
)

chain = LLMChain(llm=local_llm, prompt=prompt)
chain.run("Donald Trump")
```

I keep getting the error

> ValueError: The following `model_kwargs` are not used by the model: ['return_full_text'] (note: typos in the generate arguments will also show up in this list)

I've tried using Jupyter Notebook, Google Colab, Pycharm and yet the issuepersists

I tried asking chatgpt but to no avail.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? Please update the question with any relevant error information, logs, stack traces, etc.

Comment: Please share the full error / stacktrace you've having, that way we know which line is causing the error. Is it the `LLMChain(...)` initialization that's causing the error? Or `PromptTemplate(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a current known issue with how HuggingFace has implemented their error checks and how it throws errors. It is deliberate, but recent so some models or pipelines may still need to be updated to accomodate this.

See [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/18321) for the same error, which highlights a commit which broke LLMChain.

You may be able to downgrade your libraries to make things work, you will need to just find the versions of each library that are compatible with one another from before that specific commit.

Answer (score 0):

Since some LangChain's APIs have been deprecated, I slightly modified your code, with commenting out the unused modules for your reference and this one should work

```py
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
# from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
# from langchain import PromptTemplate, HuggingFaceHub, LLMChain
# from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, pipeline
# import os

# os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = "my api"
model_id = "google/flan-t5-xxl"
# tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
# model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
# 
# pipeline = pipeline("text2text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=128)
# local_llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline)

from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceEndpoint
local_llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
    repo_id=model_id, max_new_tokens=128, temperature=0.5)

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["name"],
    template="Can you tell me about the politician {name}"
)

chain = LLMChain(llm=local_llm, prompt=prompt)
print(chain.invoke("Donald Trump"))
```

PS. `HuggingFaceEndpoint` will be replacing `HuggingFaceHub`